# left arrow in toolbar for closing navigation drawer is not closing navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

when i am opening navigation drawer by clicking hamburger icon present in toolbar it opens it but when i click the left arrow to close the navigation drawer nothing is happening it is not closing it .please help

here is my code

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
   NavigationDrawerFragment navigationDrawerFragment;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);
    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    //findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


     navigationDrawerFragment= (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_frag);
        navigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.nav_frag,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout),(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar));


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  /*  if(actionBar!=null)
    {
     actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }*/

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cool_menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id= item.getItemId();
    if(id==android.R.id.home)
    {            ((DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout)).openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);  // OPEN DRAWER
        return true;
    }
    if(id==R.id.action_settings){
        Toast.makeText(this, "this is setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(id==R.id.action_mail){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,SubActivity.class));
    }
    if(id==R.id.action_help){
        Toast.makeText(this, "this is action_help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar"></include>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

     android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_frag"

        android:name="com.example.adarsh.material.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

NavigationDrawerFragment.java

```
           public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String FILE_NAME = "shared";
      private static final String SHARED_KEY ="shared_key" ;
     private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
     private View containerView;
     private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

       private boolean mUserLearnerDrawer;

    private boolean mFromSaveInstances;
  public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

     @Override
     public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   mUserLearnerDrawer=Boolean.valueOf(readFromSharedPreferences(getActivity(),SHARED_KEY,"false"));
    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        mFromSaveInstances=true;
    }
}

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
}

public void setup(int id,DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
   containerView=getActivity().findViewById(id);
    mDrawerLayout=drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),drawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close){
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //we are going to store the mUserLearnerDrawer in shared pref
            //if it is saved  then we will not show the drawer then we will show the drawer

            //if the user has never seeen the drawer before
            if(!mUserLearnerDrawer){
                mUserLearnerDrawer=true;
            saveToSharedPreferences(getActivity(),SHARED_KEY,mUserLearnerDrawer+"");
            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();// it going to make draw the action bar again

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    //never seen the drawer + never used it before
    if(!mUserLearnerDrawer&&!mFromSaveInstances){
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
    }
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });
}
public void saveToSharedPreferences(Context context,String name,String value){
    SharedPreferences sPrefs=context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sPrefs.edit();
    editor.putString(name,value);

    editor.apply();//apply is faster then the commit method .coz unlike    commit it does not return that yes it is commited or not
   }
public String readFromSharedPreferences(Context context,String name,String defaultValue){
    SharedPreferences   sPrefs=context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sPrefs.getString(name,defaultValue);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a global variable

```
private boolean isDrawerOpen = false;
```

then in your onOptionItemSelected do something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

int id= item.getItemId();
if(id==android.R.id.home)
{
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);
    if(isDrawerOpen){
       isDrawerOpen = false;
       drawaerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else{
       isDrawerOpen = true;
       drawaerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    return true;
}
if(id==R.id.action_settings){
    Toast.makeText(this, "this is setting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
if(id==R.id.action_mail){
    startActivity(new Intent(this,SubActivity.class));
}
if(id==R.id.action_help){
    Toast.makeText(this, "this is action_help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
return true;
}
```